# Black Scholes Geometric Brownian Motion Option Pricing

Tags: option-pricing, brownian-motion

I'm doing a past paper for one of my masters modules and I'm stuck on this

[image: This]

and I have no idea how to tackle such a thing. It's worth 30% of the exam so would be great if anyone here has any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Question (1), the payoff is given by
\begin{align*}
(S_T-S_{T_0})^+.
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{-r(T-T_0)} (S_T-S_{T_0})^+ \mid \mathscr{F}_{T_0}\right) &=S_{T_0}N(d_1)-e^{-r(T-T_0)}S_{T_0}N(d_2),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \frac{(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-T_0)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-T_0}}\\
&=(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\sqrt{T-T_0}/\sigma,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d_2 = d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{T-T_0}.
\end{align*}
The option price is then given by
\begin{align*}
C_0 &\equiv e^{-rT}E\left( (S_T-S_{T_0})^+ \right)\\
&=e^{-rT_0}E\left(E\left(e^{-r(T-T_0)} (S_T-S_{T_0})^+ \mid \mathscr{F}_{T_0}\right)\right)\\
&=e^{-rT_0}E\left(S_{T_0}N(d_1)-e^{-r(T-T_0)}S_{T_0}N(d_2) \right)\\
&=S_0 \big[N(d_1) - e^{-r(T-T_0)} N(d_2)\big].\tag{*}
\end{align*}

$$$$

For Question (2), note that
\begin{align*}
\max(S_T,\, S_{T_0}) = S_{T_0} + (S_T-S_{T_0})^+.
\end{align*}
Then, from (*), the contingent price is given by
\begin{align*}
P_0 &\equiv e^{-rT}E\left( S_{T_0} + (S_T-S_{T_0})^+ \right)\\
&=e^{-r(T-T_0)}S_0 + S_0 \big[N(d_1) - e^{-r(T-T_0)} N(d_2)\big]\\
&=S_0 \big[N(d_1) + e^{-r(T-T_0)} (1-N(d_2))\big]\\
&=S_0 \big[N(d_1) + e^{-r(T-T_0)} N(-d_2)\big].
\end{align*}